# File number generator expansion

Tags: algorithm, filenames

A previous colleague developed a file name generator based on an integer file id that came from a database record. Starting at A000 (database id 0 [zero])and counting up, the algorithm gets to A999 and then rolls over to B000, repeating all the way to Z999 at database id 25999. I need to extend this to future proof it. We're rapidly getting to Z999 and need the system to foll over to AA000 and carry on counting. I'm sure someone has dont this but I'm not sure what this system is called. It's not base 26 counting (although that would have made this much easier!)

Any suggestions on how to approach this? The original code is in VB, but I'm just looking for an algorithm I can implement. Thanks.

Comment: *It's not base 26 counting*  Indeed not, it's *mixed-radix* arithmetic, like furlongs, yards, feet and inches.  Lots of useful stuff on the Internet to inform your thinking.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. :)